# BadSyntax error while validating Datagraph against SHACL shapes in pyshacl

Tags: sparql, rdflib, shacl

I am trying to validate a data graph against a shape graph in pyshacl. The objective is to check the distance between two walls from a linked building data representation of a small building. The code I am using is below:

```
#Importing Datagraph from a file in computer
from pyshacl import validate
from rdflib import Graph
g=Graph()
Datagraph = g.parse("C:/Users/aagr657/OneDrive - The University of Auckland/UoA/Outcomes/RQ2/Models/Walls_with_Crane_LBD.ttl", format="ttl")

#Writing Shapes Graph

Shapegraph = ''' 
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix bot: <https://w3id.org/bot#> .
@prefix ifc: <https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC2x3/TC1/OWL#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix lbd: <https://linkebuildingdata.org/LBD#> .
@prefix props: <http://lbd.arch.rwth-aachen.de/props#> .
@prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> .
@prefix unit: <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit/> .
@prefix IFC4-PSD: <https://www.linkedbuildingdata.net/IFC4-PSD#> .
@prefix smls: <https://w3id.org/def/smls-owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix inst: <https://www.ugent.be/myAwesomeFirstBIMProject#> .
@prefix fog: <https://w3id.org/fog#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

ifc:geometricconstraintshape a sh:NodeShape ;
        sh:targetClass bot:Element;
        sh:sparql[
            sh:message "The geometric constraint is violated" ;
            sh:select " " "
            SELECT $this
            WHERE{
                inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353 a bot:element .
                inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd a bot:element .
                inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c353_geometry_bb lbd:x-min ?x_min .
                inst:wall_1eec9390-5f68-4a64-aaa9-34a883f3c0dd_geometry_bb lbd:x-max ?x_max .
                FILTER (ifc:computedistance(?x_min,?x_max)<=12.0) .
                } """ ;
            ] .
        
ifc:computedistance a sh:SPARQLFunction;
    rdfs:comment "Finds the distance between the two elements";
    sh:parameter[
        sh:path lbd:x_min ;
        sh:datatype xsd:double;
        sh:description "The inner x coordinate of the wall on the right side";
        ];
    
    sh:parameter[
        sh:path lbd:x_max ;
        sh:datatype xsd:double;
        sh:description "The outer x coordinate of the wall on the left side";
        ];
    
    sh:returnType xsd:double;
    sh:select"""
    SELECT (($x_min - $x_max) AS ?result)
    WHERE {
        }
    """.
'''

#Validation
r = validate(data_graph = Datagraph, shacl_graph = Shapegraph, data_graph_format="ttl", shacl_graph_format="ttl", inference = "rdfs", debug = True, abort_on_error = False, meta_shacl = False, serialize_report_graph = "ttl")
conforms, results_graph, results_text = r
```

On running the code, I am getting the following error:

```
File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3505 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Cell In[15], line 61
    r = validate(data_graph = Datagraph, shacl_graph = Shapegraph, data_graph_format="ttl", shacl_graph_format="ttl", inference = "rdfs", debug = True, abort_on_error = False, meta_shacl = False, serialize_report_graph = "ttl")

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyshacl\validate.py:439 in validate
    loaded_sg = load_from_source(

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyshacl\rdfutil\load.py:406 in load_from_source
    target_g.parse(source=cast(IO[bytes], _source), format=rdf_format, publicID=public_id)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py:2473 in parse
    c = ConjunctiveGraph.parse(

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py:2251 in parse
    context.parse(source, publicID=publicID, format=format, **args)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py:1503 in parse
    raise se

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py:1494 in parse
    parser.parse(source, self, **args)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:2021 in parse
    p.loadStream(stream)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:479 in loadStream
    return self.loadBuf(stream.read())  # Not ideal

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:485 in loadBuf
    self.feed(buf)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:511 in feed
    i = self.directiveOrStatement(s, j)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:530 in directiveOrStatement
    j = self.statement(argstr, i)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:778 in statement
    j = self.property_list(argstr, i, r[0])

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:1140 in property_list
    i = self.objectList(argstr, j, objs)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:1190 in objectList
    i = self.object(argstr, i, res)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:1487 in object
    j = self.subject(argstr, i, res)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:785 in subject
    return self.item(argstr, i, res)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:877 in item
    return self.path(argstr, i, res)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:884 in path
    j = self.nodeOrLiteral(argstr, i, res)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:1515 in nodeOrLiteral
    j = self.node(argstr, i, res)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:973 in node
    self.BadSyntax(argstr, j, "']' expected")

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\notation3.py:1730 in BadSyntax
    raise BadSyntax(self._thisDoc, self.lines, argstr, i, msg)

  File <string>
BadSyntax
```

Is it because of some problem in the Data graph, or I am making some syntax error in the shape I have written? I think the Data Graph should be alright as it is generated in the turtle format from a pre-existing converter. However, I am not able to identify the syntax error in the shape.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in line 21 of your shape you have the triple quotes broken: `sh:select "  "  "` - if that is just an issue here and not in the original data, then the shape would be valid Turtle at least.

Comment: other than that, you are providing the shape as a string - I doubt this works given the documentation states: `shacl_graph is an rdflib Graph object or file path or Web URL of the graph containing the SHACL shapes to validate with, or None if the SHACL shapes are included in the data_graph.` - so either you parse the shape also into a graph or it must be a file or URL to some file. But not a plain string like you're providing now

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser, removing the spaces in " " " after sh:select worked.